# Delete and replace desktop shortcut only if icon exists

Tags: windows, batch, icons

I am updating a desktop icon for end users, not all clients have the icon.

I need to deploy a script if icon exits delete and replace, if not stop and do not replace.

I tried the below script, but even if the icon does not exist, it will still copy the new icon.

```
IF EXIST "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Old Short*" (del /s /q "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Old Short*")
copy "\\Server1\shortcuts\New Short*" "%userprofile%\desktop\"
```

Comment: If you used incorrect term, edit the question to use proper term (and also remove the invalid tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
    if not exist "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Old Short*" goto :EOF
    del /s /q "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Old Short*"
    copy "\\Server1\shortcuts\New Short*" "%userprofile%\desktop\"
```

Comment: Yes I used the incorrect term, this has worked I have successfully deployed the required shortcut to clients with the existing or old shortcut, clients that do not have the existing or old shortcut the new shortcut has not arrived.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem. ;)